# if the key_m= 24 how to go back to the beginning in list alphabet and if done continue the process

Tags: python, if-statement, encryption, indexing, replace

if the key_m= 24 how to go back to the beginning in list alphabet and if done continue the process from index 0

the process is: take every other character in the alphabet except key1)

```
  def the_prosses():
    k = 36
    #input key= list(map(ord, key1) for exaple key1 = shadi
    c = list(map(int, (p ** x for x in m)))
    c_after_m_a = [x % k for x in c]
    c_after_m_a = list(map(int, c_after_m_a))
```

i need to do that process for every other character in the alphabet and replace it after
the `key1` like before and if the key_m reach 25 return to index 0 till it reach key_m

```
  def replace():
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'w', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    m_b = [['y'], ['a'], ['#'], ['b'], ['o'], ['i'],
       ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'], ['g'], ['h'],
       ['j'], ['k'], ['l'], ['m'], ['n'], ['p'],
       ['q'], ['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u'], ['v'],
       ['w'], ['x'], ['z'], ['_'], ['-'], ['!'],
       ['?'], ['$'], ['/'], ["@"], ['+'], ['%']]


    for idx, value in enumerate(c1, start=key_m):
        alphabet[idx] = m_b[value]
    print(alphabet)
```

the output with key_m under 25

[image: the output with key_m under 25]

Comment: Please paste the output as text, not an unreadable screenshot.

Comment: What is the premise of the exercise?  There might be a cleaner / clearer way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can use `alphabet[idx % len(alphabet)]` to wrap around.

Comment: i don't need to mod it i just want it if it reach (25 or -1) to return to 0 and if it reach key_m again stop and write output. can't it be done with if statmente ? and thanks

Comment: the premise of the exercise is to rerange the characters of key1using the_process then using the_process again to rerange all characters in alphabet except key1 because ist already reranged @S3DEV

Comment: Since you haven't defined either "m", "key1", "key_m" or "c1", I'm not sure how we can help you.  And, by the way, what you've describe is EXACTLY what `%` is for.

Comment: Also, you don't need the brackets for `m_b`.  You can write `m_b = 'ya#bvoicdefgh...'`, and it will work just as well.

Comment: thank u guys it worked i didn't understand what you was saying sorry